# Create an additional template page for every term taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms

Good day,

I am trying to add a gallery page for my website by term-taxonomy, example I have a custom type named "School" and it has 3 terms which are "grade school, highschool and college" and I also created a file named "taxonomy-schools" so I could display all the post with the same term type. Now my problem is How can I add another page so i could add a "Gallery Page" in every term. like "Pre-school (term)" should have its own gallery page under it like submenu, and High School must also have its own Gallery Page and so on... and I dont have any Idea where to start coding this. Can anyone please Help me with this one Please. Thank you Very Much!

I wanted to create a structure like this one

```
School
   GradeSchool
       Gallery (all files under the term  GradeSchool)
   HighSchool
       Gallery (all files under the term HighSchool)
   College
       Gallery (all files under the term College)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you create a template for a specific term is by a file, called taxonomy-$taxonomyname-$slug_of_the_term.php

In your case it would look like this:

taxonomy-schools-highschool.php

Use this image as a guide for any other specific case that you might have:

http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/96/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg

Comment: thank you @vlood for your answer, Im just curious, so I need to Create Every file for my term? Coz in my case im listing all the "Courses" in a college School so that would be a bunch of file that ill be creating. Is there an automated process where I dont need to manually create all the files one by one? anyways thanks again for your answer.

Comment: taxonomy-schools.php should be working for all terms under the Schools taxonomy. Only custom templates like taxonomy-schools-highschool.php will skip the usage of the general School taxonomy template.